# Why is nativescript-phone (failed to build plugin) not working on Android?

Tags: android, node.js, angular, npm, nativescript

I'm trying to build our NativeScript app to run on my Android Studio Emulator but I keep running into this certain build error:

```
> Failed to build plugin nativescript-phone : 
Error: spawn ./gradlew ENOENT
Exception in thread "DisconnectableInputStream source reader" org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:127)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:98)
```

I already tried to reinstall NativeScript, deleted my node_modules, deleted Android Studio. I've tried to delete nativescript-phone from my package.json-file, ran ns clean, ran tns debug android again but it is still not working.

My Package.json:

```
   {
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.maxtoolbox.vrsta",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.2.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.2"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.0",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.20.0",
    "nativescript-app-sync": "^1.0.7",
    "nativescript-background-http": "^4.2.1",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-datetimepicker": "^1.2.2",
    "nativescript-email": "^1.5.5",
    "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-exoplayer": "^4.0.2",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.5.0",
    "nativescript-fingerprint-auth": "^7.0.2",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.1.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.8",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.3.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-statusbar": "^1.0.19",
    "nativescript-purchase": "^2.0.13",
    "nativescript-simple-filepicker": "^1.0.2",
    "nativescript-socket.io": "^0.11.1",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^8.0.0",
    "nativescript-videoplayer": "^4.2.1",
    "nativescript-webview-interface": "^1.4.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.3.0",
    "tns-android": "6.2.0",
    "tns-ios": "6.5.3",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "a6fec076a20f898feabb4466a2c411158c18a100",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="__PACKAGE__"
          android:versionCode="69"
          android:versionName="7.1">

    <supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
            android:targetSdkVersion="30"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <application
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Valido Mitarbeiter APP"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_brightness_1" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/ns_blue" />

        <activity
                android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|.screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" 
 android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>

        <service 
 android:name="org.nativescript.plugins.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service 
 android:name="org.nativescript.plugins.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

My globally installed stuff:

```
NativeScript: 8.2.2
NPM: 8.5.2
Node: 17.7.1
Angular: 8.0.6
```

(if it's still relevant) I'm working on a device with M1-chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it with upgrading to the latest NativeScript Version 8.2.3

works fine now.